# WSO2 ESB Fault Sequence for Store and Forward with REST API

Tags: jms, wso2-esb

Currently we use the Store and Forward pattern in WSO2 ESB. So when a message comes into a proxy we use a sequence to move it into a store (queue) and then have a message processor to process the queued messages and send them to our REST API i.e. process the messages asynchronously. However when the REST API throws 400, 404, 409 or 422 the processor stops (same for 50X errors). We'd like to move these failed message for 4XX status codes to a separate queue where they can be diagnosed and dealt with. This means if there is one bad message it doesn't stop the remaining queued messages being processed. We only want to do this for 4XX faults. 5XX or network issues/timeouts should continue to stop the processor. I've looked into the Dead Letter Channel (https://docs.wso2.com/display/IntegrationPatterns/Dead+Letter+Channel) but this seems only compatible with Proxy (synchronous requests). So instead I'm trying to use a Fault Sequence to move the message to another queue however the fault sequence only seems to work with SOAP faults. Is it possible to get it to work with REST API status code faults? https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Error+Handling

I noticed it possible to add status codes but this seems only useful to reduce retry attempts. Thanks in advance.

---

**FOLLOW UP**

I tried to trigger a fault sequence for my REST API as suggested by @Jean-Michel but still the fault sequence doesn't run. Try it for yourself with these steps.

Step 1: add a proxy

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
   name="TestProxy"
   transports="https,http"
   statistics="disable"
   trace="disable"
   startOnLoad="true">
<target faultSequence="DeadLetterQueueSequence">
  <inSequence>
     <log level="custom" category="ERROR">
        <property name="TEST" value="Proxy was hit"/>
     </log>
  </inSequence>
  <endpoint>
     <address uri="http://localhost:8080/sampleService/failEndpoint400"/>
  </endpoint>
</target>
<description/>
</proxy>
```

Step 2:  Add the dead letter sequence:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="DeadLetterQueueSequence" trace="disable">
<log level="full" category="ERROR">
  <property name="Test" value="DeadLetterQueueSequence was hit"></property>
</log>
</sequence>
```

The 1st log entry appears but never the 2nd (from the DeadLetter sequence).

It seems that the WSO2 ESB isn't REST friendly and only works well with SOAP services.

Answer (score 0):

In your Message Processor conf (forwardnig), instead of sending the messages from the store directly to your REST API, you can send them to a proxy service inside the ESB and in it's outSequence, you can test the status code, the content of the response, etc. and eventually decide to move the message into another store.

In this outSequence, you can choose to respond to your Message Processor with a status code :

- 200 or 500 : the reply sequence will be executed (and the message will be removed from the store)
- any other status code : the faul sequence will be executed (and the message will stay in the sotre)

Comment: thanks for the reply. I thought of this also but decided against it because I felt it might be bad practice due to the unnecessary extra network hop.

Comment: A message forwarding processor dequeue the messages from the store one by one, sequentially : only one http thread will be used at a given time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parameter "Non retry http status codes" of the message processor to prevent that from going into deactivate status. Then in the reply sequence, you can handle the failed message by sending that to a Dead Letter Queue or whatever way you want.

```
<messageProcessor name="SampleProcessor" class="org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ScheduledMessageForwardingProcessor" targetEndpoint="stockEP" messageStore="SampleStore" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <parameter name="interval">1000</parameter>
   <parameter name="client.retry.interval">1000</parameter>
   <parameter name="message.processor.reply.sequence">replySeq</parameter>
   <parameter name="message.processor.fault.sequence">faultSeq</parameter>
   <parameter name="is.active">true</parameter>
   <parameter name="non.retry.status.codes">500</parameter>
</messageProcessor>
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work. I tried various combinations but no luck. It seems that neither the fault or reply sequence run. I am ready to give up on WSO2 ESB because it isn't supporting this feature simply. It seems that even with complex work arounds it doesn't work.